# PHP cache script won't cache the php-file

Tags: php, caching

I am trying to cache a PHP file which was succesful on one site, but when I implented the code on another website it doesn't get cached. I checked it with Firebug and I get an `200 OK` status, which means it downloads it from the server everytime the page refreshes.

Here is my code:

```
$now          = time();
$generatedAt  = gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s T', $now);
$lastModified = gmdate('D, d M Y 00:00:00 T', $now);
$expiresAt    = gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s T', strtotime($lastModified) + 8035200);
$maxAge       = strtotime($expiresAt) - strtotime($generatedAt);

header('Last-modified: '.$lastModified);
header('Cache-control: max-age='.$maxAge);
```

**Extra info:**

It is copied from my other site which I get an `304 NOT MODIFIED` status which means it does get cached.

This code is at the top of the file, no echos or output which means no headers are sent yet.

My .htaccess file is configured correctly either, I did not specify that it shouldn't cache PHP files.

Comment: Do you use sessions in the script that's trying to be cached?

Comment: No sessions in the script neither in my whole website

Comment: Okay.  PHP likes sending cache-busting headers when sessions are involved.  Can you check and see what the actual headers are that the requesting script sees?  It'll be useful to have them, and will make it very obvious what's actually happening.

Comment: there is one more header right under header(cache-control) which is: header(content-type)

Comment: No, what I mean is, the *actual headers* sent over the wire, not the specific ones you set.  The web server software is likely to add things like the date and time, etc.

Comment: Tro to see which headers are really sent from your webserver (in your both sites)

Comment: You can use `curl -I URL` on Linux or [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/network) on a Windows client to read the sent headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try other browsers? Firefox' caching is a steaming pile of *****, to say the least. Also, .htaccess is not the only thing - the Apache configuration will most likely need some adjustment in the AllowOverride directive for the directory where the script is in.

Also, try using Wireshark to observe what goes over the network - what headers are sent and what headers are really recieved?

Answer (score -1):

I suppose that you should fix this `Last-modified:` parameter.